# Getting timeout issue for ice candidate collection

Tags: javascript, webrtc, chromium-embedded

During the call with WebRTC app in CEF3, I am getting below Errors. I have done a lot analysis but could not figure it out reason/solution of this issue..
Please suggest what is the problem & what is the solution.

```
1448447657717 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - ICE candidate received: sdpMLineIndex = 1, candidate = candidate:1972606970 2 tcp 1518214910 10.12.1.104 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0 for call : undefined
1448447658619 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447659623 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447660625 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447661628 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447662630 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447663632 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447664635 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447665636 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Re-setting ice candidate collection timeout: 1000
1448447666638 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - Ice candidate collection interrupted after given timeout, invoking successCallback.
1448447666639 - WebRtcAdaptorImpl - previous mute state of call: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a chromium bug. upgrade to chromimum 47, this problem doesn't exist.

Please follow the below link that has simpler problem. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/7AZlGM8EQUI/XW9c_YyzmeYJ

One developer has raised the below issue that got resolved on  Aug 2015.
Raised issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4215